# read.csv() columns NULL

Tags: r, excel

This is a very simple question I hope, but just can't seem to solve myself.

I'm trying to read a .csv file of integers into R using read.csv(), however for analysis reasons I need to convert all the integers in some of the column into characters, which I do using `dataframe$column[i]=toString(dataframe$column[i])`. However, for some reason the dataframe does not seem to work as I expect. `levels(dataframe$column)` always gives NULL, both before and after conversion.

Can anyone help me import my .csv file into R with integers of some of the columns as characters, and those characters defining the levels of those columns?

Thanks to anyone who may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

levels() means that the column is a categorical variable. Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), b = c(6, 7, 8, 8, 10))
df$b <- as.factor(as.character(df$b))
```

Each entry in b is now a string, and the column is a categorical variable with levels "10", "6", "8", "7".

toString will convert the entire column into a string, and entered into every row. If you indeed want to convert the entire column into a string and entered for every row and have levels, then simply use factor:

```
 dataframe$column[i]=factor(toString(dataframe$column[i]))
```